# Java: How to add a button to a frame?

Tags: java, bluej

I try to just use a add.method to add a button to a frame. But only the frame pops up.
I don't see any buttons.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class okd {
    public static void main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton b1 = new JButton();
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.add(b1);
        b1.setSize(400,400);
        b1.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your button has been added to the frame. You'll notice a difference if you remove your `frame.add()` line. The 'problem' lies with the following.

- You haven't specified a layout resulting in your frame using the
  default BorderLayout manager.
- You haven't specified a constraint in `frame.add()`. Because of this the
  component has been added to whatever the default position is for the
  layout which is `BorderLayout.CENTER`. Components added to the center
  take up the much space as possible hence why your button is filling the entire frame.

Here's some tutorials [on layout managers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) You might want to have a read through these at some point.

Answer (score 7):

There is a button there. Add some text to it and it will magically appear.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton b1 = new JButton();
    frame.setSize(500,500);     
    b1.setSize(400,400);
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setText("HelloWorld");
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}//SSCCE1
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. But it doesn't look like the button I expected. :D Do you know how to do that? Like a real button on a frame.

Comment: What do you mean by "real button" - can you link an example of what a real button is?

Comment: @user3105629: I can't know how you're expecting it to be, but I can direct you [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). The button here *is* clickable, just click it and see.

Comment: Never mind. The button's size is as big as the whole frame. That's why I think that is not a button. Thank you guys

Comment: I have the same problem. The button covers the whole frame

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Large appearance of the button, You need to add a layout Manager to the Code
Like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton b1 = new JButton();
    frame.setSize(500,500); 
    b1.setVisible(true);
    b1.setText("HelloWorld");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(b1);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question - the question is asking why the button doesn't appear, but this answer is to "remove the Large appearance of the button".

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave: Man!!! Check out the last comment on the list.My reply was to that one.

Comment: I see; that's not very clear though. The question-and-answer format of SO doesn't really lend itself to that sort of conversational answer - it's not a forum. Ideally, this additional complication would be a separate question, where your answer would be relevant, but that seems like overkill, as the accepted answer from PakkuDon already basically says the same thing.